# Hide and show Complete action shortcut in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I searched a lot but didn't find any solution that work for me.

I am developing a plugin for wordpress that will work only with woocommerce. So i want that when my order status is in pending state i want to hide complete action shortcut on orders listing page.

[image]

In the above picture i want to hide middle button when my order is in pending state. I want to do it in plugin.

Any suggestion.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How and where to call?

Comment: ajax call for checking order status and  hide button according to return status.

Comment: I want that in my plugin so how i will add this in any hooks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this can be done using 'woocommerce_admin_order_actions' filter  and adding a function to a filter.

**Code to be added in you plugin:**

`add_filter('woocommerce_admin_order_actions','wdm_verify_product_limitation',5,2);
function wdm_verify_product_limitation( $actions, $the_order ){
    if ( $the_order->has_status( array( 'pending','on-hold') ) ) {
    unset($actions['complete']);
    }
    return $actions;
}`

Here i am checking if the order is in 'pending' or 'on-hold' state then don't show the Complete button for that order.**(in your case remove  'on-hold' from the code )**

[image]

Have tested the same. Do let me know if this works for you